# Why are there no consumption plans for API apps?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-app-service-plans

If I deploy a bunch of Azure Functions in to a functions app and setup the functions app to use a consumption plan, then each calendar month the compute cost for the first 1 million calls is basically free.

How come I can't do this with a web API using something like MVC or OData?
The only difference I can see is the framework parts used, presumably there's some infrastructural reason for this?

Which leads to ...
I'm tempted to make all API implementations a set of Azure Functions to make the most of cloud costs but it feels like I'm making the infrastructure costs dictate my technical decisions a little too much here or that I'm missing something.

As a sort of secondary question if there's any MSFT peeps out there, would Microsoft consider making it so that all Azure app Services can be consumption planned?

Comment: Look at Azure Container Apps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The big difference between an App Service and a Function App is the fact that, for your App Service, there's an App Service Plan dedicated to run the App Service which reserves a set of resources like CPU and memory.

> An App Service plan defines a set of compute resources for a web app to run. These compute resources are analogous to the server farm in conventional web hosting. One or more apps can be configured to run on the same computing resources (or in the same App Service plan).
>
> When you create an App Service plan in a certain region (for example, West Europe), a set of compute resources is created for that plan in that region. Whatever apps you put into this App Service plan run on these compute resources as defined by your App Service plan.

Source: [Azure App Service plan overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-hosting-plans)

For a Function App on a Consumption Plan, this is a *specialized version* of an App Service Plan. In that case you have a lot less to say about how that plan is configured or what resources it gets: that's all abstracted away for you as a user.

> When you're using the Consumption plan, instances of the Azure Functions host are dynamically added and removed based on the number of incoming events. The Consumption plan is the fully serverless hosting option for Azure Functions.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/consumption-plan

And while the Azure Functions Host is the application constantly handling requests by checking to see if your Function App is being called and requests need to be *passed on* to your code, in a more traditional application like an MVC app, it is *your application* that actually handles the request beginning to end.

**EDIT**

> why can't I put an MVC controller up on the same contract terms in the cloud as I can with an azure function

Because the current implementation of an App Service is "analogous to the server farm in conventional web hosting", meaning it expects an entire web application. An Azure Function expects a piece of code that can handle the request (better: trigger). A controller is more than just that, and has some (a lot...?) of fluff around it to be able to work.

And, somewhat simplified: because it hasn't been made available by Azure. Presumably because it would make Azure Functions way too biased on how the (.NET, HTTP triggered) function should be implemented.

Abstraction: a Function is a piece of code that can handle a trigger. This trigger can be a lot of things, one of which is a HTTP request. From the Functions runtime's point of view, all triggers just need to be mapped to a handler. Currently, that handler could be considered framework agnostic, Azure Functions only prescribes it adheres to a certain signature.

By allowing developers to host an MVC Controller as the handler for an Azure Function, this would also mean it needs to have all the fluff around the controller either be in place (what, how, ... ?) or the controller be slimmed down to 'just' be a handler for a HTTP trigger... which would make it a regular Azure Function.

Comment: My question was more ... if a consumption plan is a type of app service plan then why can't API's be served up like functions apps ... both are essentially sets of microservice endpoints to handle busines functions are they not?

Comment: To be clear ... I do understand the difference between an app service plan and a consumption plan ... I'm trying to understand why I can't put an MVC controller up on the same contract terms in the cloud as I can with an azure function. Do you see my point?

Comment: It's a subtle difference I don't think i'll understand, but thanks for the input.